Get path to Exiftool.exe in PyExiftool under Win (11)
Is there a way to find out what path the pyexiftool Python library is using for the Exiftool.exe under Wind 11?

No.  It doesn't use a path, it relies on the PATH environment variable.  Quote: If exiftool is not on the PATH, you can specify the full pathname to it by using ExifTool(executable={full path})

Thank you. I had missed that when reading the documentation
